# accessing a local virtual host from outside LAN as virtual host like http://sitename instead of http://systemname/sitename

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am developing a site and that that is managed by two. one is me and the other is the designer accessing from different machines across LAN.

Conf: php, apache, windows xp, mysql.

Document root: d:\www\xampp\htdocs. all the projects are under this as subfolders.

I have set up virtual host so that i will not access all the projects as http://localhost/foldername but just as http://foldername.

But for the designer who is in the other system he has to access like http://computername/foldername

For example let me be working in a project payroll. i will access that as http://payroll but my designer will access that as http://computername/payroll.

What i want to do is i want the designer to access the same way i access. that is http://payroll.

so that in the designer system when the server name is payroll i want it to be directed to my machine and then to the project folder. so if he gives http://payroll then the application in my system should run for him.

i have setup the hosts file in the designer system to point to my machine. so this work is done and when he gives payroll my http://localhost is appearing.

what should i do so the designer can access my project like http://payroll form his system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The designer has to add your IP address with each `sitename` to his [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) as without it his browser won't know where to look for the site. It could look like this:

```
12.34.56.78 sitename1
12.34.56.78 sitename2
12.34.56.78 repeat.for.each.sitename
...
```

This might be enough if your VirtualHosts are not bound to a specific IP address. This would not work:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName sitename1
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

It should be:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sitename1
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This way apache will serve the site called `sitename` whenever it sees a request with the hostname `sitename` and it won't matter if it came from the same computer or not.

Comment: for me it is showing access forbidden but other computers were able to access.

Comment: i was having my hosts file like 127.0.0.1 sitename1 which said access forbidden where as for the other users it worked because they have given my ip in their hosts file. like that if i only give my 192.168.1.20 sitename1 then it is working. but all other vhosts where showing access forbidden... so if my ip changes then i think i thould change my hosts file and replace the ip with the new ip and the same for the others. isnt there any other way?

Comment: it works when i replace all 127.0.0.1 with my ip for all instances in conf file. and need to do some more changes to make it work what i expected. anyway. thank you.

Comment: yes. it worked. but... if i have another project in http://localhost/some/ that too is redirecting to http://payroll...

Answer (score 1):

He can put into his \windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file:

```
1.2.3.4 payroll
```

Where 1.2.3.4 should be replaced with the IP number of the system.

The Apache sites-enabled\000-default file should start with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # from http://www.iliveinperego.com/2008/05/automatic-vhost-with-apache/
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$
        RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /%1$1
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: yes it works but my site in in a subfolder of the root folder and i want that subfolder project to run and not the root folder

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood you to say you had fixed the Apache setup for that. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: didn't the rewrites work for you? that's the way I've got my system set up, so I know it can work.

Comment: what is... The Apache sites-enabled\000-default file... where the file is located?

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default on Debian. don't know about Windows, but if you search for sites-enabled you ought to be able to find it.

Comment: oh. ok.  thank you. besides can you comment on my dout in the other answer? if possible.